# Code to retrieve attachments from outlook to a specific folder

Tags: r, outlook, com

I am trying to write an R code to download attachments from emails with a specific subject to a specific folder. With the help of some information in this website I was able to write the initial part, but I face an error since the beginning.

I tried using the library [RDCOMClient](http://www.omegahat.net/RDCOMClient/).

```
library(RDCOMClient)

outlook_app <- COMCreate("Outlook.Application")
outlookNameSpace = outlook_app$GetNameSpace("MAPI")
folder <- outlookNameSpace$Folders(1)$Folders('Inbox')
```

I get the following error:

```
<checkErrorInfo> 80020009 
No support for InterfaceSupportsErrorInfo
checkErrorInfo -2147352567
Error: Exception occurred."
```

If anyone can help I would really be grateful, or if anyone has a better code I can use, it would be really helpful.

Comment: Are you sure it knows `folder <- outlookNameSpace$Folders(1)$Folders('Inbox')`? Have you tried breaking this up?

Comment: I tried with different folders, I tried "inbox" and some archive ones but still nothing.

Comment: Have you also tried with different indexes? Like 2 or 3 instead of 1?

Comment: Thank you, with number 3 it works, but now I am stuck at finding a specific email in the folder.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: This is what I tried  [ search <- outlook_app$AdvancedSearch(
  "Inbox",
  "subject = 'The email subject i'm trying to download'"
)]

Comment: Try the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54444097/using-rdcomclient-to-search-outlook-inbox)